# A problem about finding the probability a random variable is bigger than another random variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

I'm studying statistics through Khan Academy and it had this question:

> "Yuki and Zana are on a swimming team. They often compete against each
>   other in the 100 meter freestyle race. Yuki's times in this race are
>   normally distributed with a mean of 80 seconds and a standard
>   deviation of 4.2 seconds. Zana's times are also
>   normally distributed with a mean of 85 seconds and a standard
>   deviation of 5.6 seconds. We can assume that their
>   times are independent.
>
> Suppose we choose a random 100-meter freestyle race and calculate the
>   difference between their times.
>
> Find the probability that Yuki's time is faster than Zana's."

Khan Academy's answer to the question is 0.7611 or approximately 0.76. I've spent hours working on this problem and I frustratingly keep on ending up with an answer of 0.2389. Can someone please help me on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like you got the question inversed (you calculated probability that Yuki's time is more, not less). For example, there is probability of $1/2$ Yuki's time is less than $80$, and probability of $1/2$ that Zana's time is greater then $85$, so probability of Yuki's time is faster than Zana's is obviously at least $1/2 \cdot 1/2 = 0.25$.

Answer (score 1):

I had the very same issue. As @mihaild mentions in the comment, your solution is the inverse of the true one. The real reason for this is in the text though.

What you (and I) calculated was the probability that Yuki's **time is greater** than Zana's. However, the question is about the probability that Yuki's **time is faster**, not **greater**. Because, of course, she is faster when her time is **lower**.